# Where should I add require autotest to my autotest file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, autotest, growl

I am creating a new rails app as a learning project. I have already completed a rails app store for college but I am now trying to start a new app now knowing a bit more i didn't before. I wish to test the app correctly so I am following the micheal hartl tutorial for setting up the test environment. I have installed everything okay but there is a point where i must add

```
require 'autotest-growl'
```

and

```
require 'autotest-fsevent'
```

to my .autotest file. I have done this tutorial before, but I have read some more on rspec and autotest since.(not too much though)
So my question(s) are 
Should the autotest file be in the same directory as my project?
Where is it currently installed (i found it in c:/ruby192/bin where i have ruby installed) ?
I am on a windows 7 machine, using rails 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, those two `require` lines are pointless... they both are specific for Mac OS X.

You should be able to proceed without the file just fine; you won't have the Growl notifications the tutorial may refer to, but you'll still see your test output in the console/command line.

Comment: Nice one thanks, I didn't remember if I followed that step or not before.